# Products out of stock with inventory

Tags: backend, inventory, stock

My inventory is updated frequently via webservices/cron.  My issue is that if a product goes "out of stock", the check box remains "out of stock" even when new inventory is showing up.  For example, a product had a quantity of 0 for a couple of weeks so the "out of stock" box was checked at the backend automatically.  Now the stock levels have updated to 300 and the product will not automatically display at the front without me needing to manually uncheck the "out of stock" box at the back.  With thousands of products in my catalogue and stock levels constantly updating, it's not practical for me to do this.  Can anyone tell me how to have Magento automatically display an item as "in stock" when the inventory is above 1?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a feature of Magento. This allows you to set a product "out of stock" (if you have reasons to) independent from the product qty. The simplest solution would be to modify the cron that sets the product quantities to set the 'is_in_stock' flag on the inventory item to `1` it the qty is 1 or above. Maybe you should post some code from your cron and we can help you change it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Call it a feature or a lack, it depends on specific store's needs. This thread here fixes your issue and I also posted a module link which address this issue:
[Stock item not put back in stock automatically upon reaching positive inventory](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72756/stock-item-not-put-back-in-stock-automatically-upon-reaching-positive-inventory/138760#138760)